# Exchange messages between nodes with a new map and without accidents

Tags: omnet++, veins

I executed the Veins example with the erlangen map and I put **node[*0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 0**, I noticed, during simulation, that there was no exchange of messages between nodes which is logical.

I have generated my .rou.xml, .poly.xml and .net.xml files from SUMO and then I imported the new map in Veins. When I put **accidentCount = 0** in the omnetpp.ini file, I noticed that there was exchange of messages between nodes.
I  want to know which these messages mean please?

Comment: You can find the code that is used in the tutorial's application layer online: https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L94 - from there, you should be able to determine what causes messages to be sent and how this might apply to your modified simulation

Comment: Thank you for you response Sir, I just generated the .rou.xml, .poly.xml and .net.xml files from SUMO and I imported them into Veins and I have not changed the code source of TracIDemo11p.cc. When I simulate it there are data transfer between nodes, how can I please identify the reason of message exchange?

Comment: I am afraid that this will require you to understand the C++ code of the demo application. Without that, the simulation framework will simply not be of any help to you.